# Using Composer on Shared Host

Tags: magento2, composer

I have just recently started dabbling in the idea of upgrading from Magento 1.9.x to 2.2.x now.

Working with installing Mangento and now having to use Composer, I am attempting to run simple commands but I am constantly running out of allocated memory.

I imagine this could become a pretty common issue on shared servers as we are typically not allowed to change the memory limits.

Are there alternatives to using Composer to upgrade/install new extensions? Is there a work around to working with Composer under such restrictions?

Comment: Magento 2 always recommend higher configuration so it wouldn't work with shared hosting with lower configuration